# Angular 2 routing with map

Tags: angular

I createad a few components on map. A component must be appear according to the routing path. The map always must be appear. For example if path is 'localhost:4200/investment' then InvestmentComponent must be appear on map. For example if path is 'localhost:4200/layers' then LayersComponent must be appear on map. HomeComponent is a static page. InvestmentComponent and LayersComponent must be work on map. I created an example. Here the problem is when the path is 'localhost:4200/layers' or 'localhost:4200/investment' the map is creating twice time. İs there a best way? How can I do?

**App.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {InitService} from './services/init.service';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './partials/navbar/navbar.component';
import {InvestmentComponent} from './map/investment/investment.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {MapComponent} from './map/map.component';
import { LayersComponent } from './map/layers/layers.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'layers', component: MapComponent},
    {path: 'investment', component: MapComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MapComponent,
        InvestmentComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LayersComponent,
        NavbarComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes
        )
    ],
    providers: [InitService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {    
}
```

**MapComponent.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {InitService} from '../services/init.service';

declare let L;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-map',
    templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['map.component.scss']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router, public init: InitService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      init();
    }

    init(){
        const lat = 26.86663;
        const lng = 54.98663;
        const globalMap = L.map('mapContainer', {
            zoomControl: true,
            maxZoom: 21,
            minZoom: 4
        }).setView([lat, lng], 13);
        globalMap.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');
        const maplayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&hl=tr&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
            subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
            maxNativeZoom: 21,
            zIndex: 0,
            maxZoom: 21
        }).addTo(globalMap);       
   }
}
```

MapComponent.html

```
    <div class="adrCenter overflow-hidden">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="adrRow" class="row">
            <div id="adrColLeft" class="adrCol scrollbar col-2">
                <app-layers *ngIf="router.url == '/layers'"></app-layers>
                <app-investment *ngIf="router.url == '/investment'"></app-investment>
            </div>
            <div id="adrColCenter" class="adrCol col-10">                 
                </div>
                <div #mapContainer id="mapContainer" class="active" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you consider changing your routes?

Comment: Yes I want to change routes I edited my question you can see MapComponent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider changing your routes, here's something that you can do:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '', component: MapComponent, children: [
    {path: 'layers', component: LayersComponent},
    {path: 'investment', component: InvestmentComponent}
  ]}
];
```

I've created a route for your `HomeComponent`. And an empty route(`''`) as a parent route for your `MapComponent`.

Now, all you need to do is add the map to your `MapComponent` along with a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that is going to host the template of your `LayersComponent` and `InvestmentComponent`.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-maps-sample?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for your ref.

---

**NOTE:** Note that I've installed [**`ngx-leaflet`**](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) to load the map.

Comment: Yes I have done your told. But the problem is when call a path map is loading more then. How can I solve?

Comment: Also I add check for router with ngIf. İs there another method?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: I completed. I installed leaflet npm. But Leaflet doesnt install. you can see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5xamm

Comment: @Hermes, I've updated my answer with a Working Sample StackBlitz.

Comment: Thank you so much. You really helped me so much. I have a last question. I used this method *ngIf="router.url == '/layers'" for to show component is it correct method? or what is the best method?